# How to disable Sparkle's warning about GC?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, garbage-collection, sparkle

I'm using the Sparkle framework in Xcode 5. When I build I see the following warning. Is there a way to disable (quiet) this warning without changing the fact that Sparkle uses GC?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is is maybe what you're after, in the Sparkle Xcode project:

1. Select the project itself to show the various target settings etc
2. Select Sparkle under **PROJECT**
3. Select the Info group (from the "tab bar" along the top of the pane
4. Under **Configurations** delete the third one, release dual mode

This removes the configuration which supports Sparkle dual-mode with GC and should remove the warnings. The standard Release configuration does not use GC.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Use [up-to-date fork of Sparkle](https://github.com/pornel/Sparkle) that is maintained for XCode 5.

Answer (score 0):

The latest development version of Sparkle now uses Automatic Reference Counting and will likely be available in Sparkle version 1.8.